# SQL: Using a listbox value in LIKE function call

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working with a database of movies. Some movies have multiple genres under their "listed_in" category (ie Drama, Horror). I have a listbox that has each individual genre (ie Drama). I'm trying to use the query below, but it returns no value. I think it's because it's looking for the "forms!..." instead of what the actual value is. Is there a way to work around this?

```
SELECT title
FROM Catalogue
WHERE Catalogue.listed_in LIKE "*forms![Genre_frm]![Genre_lbx].Value*";
```

Comment: It sounds like you need a many to many relationship. One movie can have one or more categories and a category can be found in 0 or more movies. Based on that you need to filter your result set by using joins and then filtering the join. In this case you likely need category ids and then you can filter the movies by the category id from the relationship. That is assuming that your drop down has a name/value pair where the name is the category ID and the value is the category title. Hope this gets you going in the correct direction.

Comment: **Don't put the form/control reference within quote marks.** `LIKE` without concatenated `*` wildcard might as well just use = sign.  Is value of listbox the descriptive Title or an ID? What is the listbox RowSource? Is listbox set for Multi-Select? Listbox is UNBOUND?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
WHERE Catalogue.listed_in LIKE "'*" & Forms![Genre_frm]![Genre_lbx] & "*'";
```